# What is div itemtype? I have a review site what can be the value of itemtype for my site?

Tags: html, microdata

If i use `<div>` tag `itemprop="review"` itemscope `itemtype="http://mydomainname.com/Review"` itemtype then do i need to create a page named review on my site?

Comment: I'm not sure if this will be of much use, but `itemtype` and `itemprop` are part of the HTML5 Microdata spec: http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/microdata.html#attr-itemtype

Answer (score 9):

I'd suggest you read [this tutorial](http://www.htmlgoodies.com/html5/Web-Developer-Tutorial-HTML5-Microdata-3920016.htm#fbid=VCU32R9FqvD) on HTML5 microdata.  Here's an excerpt from that document about `itemtype`:

> The itemscope attribute us used to indicate that the element it is
>   placed on and it’s children represent a microdata item. The itemscope
>   should be paired with an itemtype attribute that defines the microdata
>   vocabulary in use.
>
> `<p itemscope itemtype="http://www.data-vocabulary.org/Organization/">` ...
>
> Additional data ...
>
> Microdata vocabularies can be nested and can
>   be dependent on one another. For example, the organization microdata
>   vocabulary also contains an address as a member. The itemtype url can
>   point to anything. Think of it as just a unique character string that
>   various programs have agreed that when they see that specific ID, they
>   know how to parse and look for the itemprop tags in the sub-elements
>   to extract the meaning needed from the document.

There are predefined `itemtype` values or you can create your own.  They may be URLs, but do not have to be.

Here are some other references on the topic (there are many more in a Google search for "html5 microdata":

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/html5-microdata-welcome-to-the-machine/

http://diveintohtml5.info/extensibility.html

http://www.tutorialspoint.com/html5/html5_microdata.htm

Answer (score 6):

No, the `itemtype` values are syntactically URLs but the URLs need not correspond to any resource (though they often do), and browsers or search engines are not expected to use the URLs for accessing resources. Rather, they are just identifiers.

But search engines tend to look for *specific* identifiers of this kind, not anything that you or I could make up. If you are using microdata for your own search system, you can use anything you like of course.

Some major search engines have established [schema.org](http://schema.org), which can be regarded as the de facto standard in this area. So for microdata on reviews for example, check their [Review](http://schema.org/Review) module. It uses `itemtype="http://schema.org/Review"`.

Caveat: Search engines that recognize microdata apparently do so for certain types of large sites (commercial and community) sites only. This may change, but it is unrealistic to expect that a typical website could have its pages into the searches based on microdata just by adding microdata attributes to tags.